# Cannot read property 'makeCurrent' of undefined in angular mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I've done according to angular mobile, https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/blob/master/guides/cli-setup.md

Node version `v4.4.3`
NPM version `2.15.1`

Problem is when I type `$ ng serve` encounter following error.

```
Cannot read property 'makeCurrent' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'makeCurrent' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/PWA/hello-mobile/node_modules/angular2-universal/dist/node/node.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/PWA/hello-mobile/node_modules/angular2-universal/dist/node/index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/PWA/hello-mobile/node_modules/angular2-broccoli-prerender/dist/prerender.js:8:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

Comment: I get the same problem when running ng build as well... npm -v 3.10.3, node -v 6.1.0

Comment: Upgrade angular-universal dependency in your package.json  to 0.104.4 and do an npm update. Your initial build will succeed how ever any progressive builds will again fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok finally got it working. Update package.json in your root folder like below

```
"angular2-broccoli-prerender": "0.11.3",
"angular2-universal": "0.104.4",
```

Also add

```
"child-process-promise": "^2.0.2",
"optimist": "^0.6.1"
```

then

```
> npm update
```

This will make it working again

Comment: great, you make my day.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by just updating the two packages mentioned by Aswin.

The latest/working versions at the time were:

```
"angular2-broccoli-prerender": "0.11.5",
"angular2-universal":"0.104.5",
```